# Fortran SIZE() gives unclassified statement

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

My program contains the following simple function:

```
contains

  real function mean(array)
    implicit none

    real, dimension(:), intent(in)    :: array
    integer                           :: size

    size = size(array)
    mean = sum(array)/max(1,size)
    return
 end function mean
```

But for some reason when I try to compile it with gfortran, it returns an "unclassified statement" error for this line:

```
size = size(array)
```

I don't understand why that is or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have told the compiler that the symbol size is an integer - overriding the intrinsic function which is no longer accessible. Try calling the variable something different. There must be a duplicate here but no time to search.

Comment: You cannot call a local variable `size` and retain access to the intrinsic function `size`.  With `integer size` you are declaring that the _function_ size returns an integer (not declaring a local variable) but you cannot use the function on the left-hand side of the assignment `size=size(array)`. Detail of this is in the answer to the linked question: in short call your size variable something other than `size`.

Comment: I did try calling it something else. I called it asize and it still didn't work.

Comment: Ooooh I figured out why it didn't work, I had also declared "size" in the program that contains the function, this is why it was overriding the function even when I changed the name inside the function.